# If $\gcd(a,p)=1$, $p$ is prime, prove that there are $1\le x, y\le [\sqrt p]$ that $ax≡y\pmod p$ or $ax≡-y\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, residue-calculus

If $\gcd(a,p)=1$, $p$ is prime, prove that there are $1\le x, y\le [\sqrt p]$ that $ax≡y\pmod p$ or $ax≡-y\pmod p$

I met this when looking
proof of  theory which says if $p=4k+1$ then there are $a,b$ that $a^2+b^2=p$. My question is how to prove that the above fact is always true for any $a$.

Comment: This fact is known as Thue's lemma. See, for example, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%27s_lemma.

Comment: To prove that, consider all pairs $(m,n)\in\{0,1,\ldots, [\sqrt{p}]\}$ and residues of $am+n\pmod p$. Since $([\sqrt{p}]+1)^2>p$ there will be two distinct pairs with the same residue $am+n\pmod p$.